# Is there a way to clear HSTS without an SSL cert?

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, hsts

Recently, I switched the server for my site, and I managed to lose the decrypted SSL key, and I cannot remember the password for the encrypted one.
It turned out that the server had set HSTS on, and now many visitors are unable to load the pages since I don't have a valid SSL cert, and their browsers refuse to connect via http due to the HSTS.

So, *I need a way to disable that HSTS from their browsers*. Asking them to clear browsing data is a no-go, but I was wondering if I could make a firefox/chrome compatible javascript to clear it. (The script would be on a different domain)

I've been digging around a bit, but haven't found much info on how I should approach the problem, if it is even possible. All other suggestions are welcome too.

Comment: Every browser has that list stored somewhere, but it will likely require manual steps to clear. That's the point of HSTS: you take responsibility of always providing an SSL connection and in return you increase security for your visitors. The best course of action would really be to install a valid certificate again.

Comment: http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers

Comment: I will most likely install a self-signed cert to get around this problem. Still worth asking, and I'm interested if there are ways to automate this from a webpage. It may be worth noting that the cert I used was a free one from startcom

Comment: A self-signed cert will only be useful if you also install it into your visitor's trust stores. Otherwise the browser won't trust your site any more than if it had no certificate at all. Just get another free or cheap certificate from somewhere, it's not that hard or expensive.

Comment: Yes, but at least it will give you an option to trust it. I never really required https for the site anyways, as it is 99% used as an imagehost.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how a browser would behave in the face of a self-signed cert with HSTS set. It should simply refuse it and not even give you the option to trust it. You'd have to manually install the cert into the trust store; at which point you may as well clear the HSTS flag manually.

Comment: Damn, you might be right on that.. Now that you say, I do recall reading/seeing something like that also. I guess that leaves me only the choice of getting a new SSL cert from somewhere... (Startcom won't let me re-create it until it expires, and if you want to revoke it, it'll cost around 20usd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HSTS is there to make a tradeoff: you take responsibility to from now and forever provide a secure SSL connection which the browser can count on, which will cause the browser to refuse anything but an SSL connection to your domain. It puts an additional burden on you, but increases security for your visitors.

The browser stores this preference in an internal database **which cannot be cleared by any website**. If it'd be possible for any site to simply revoke this preference via Javascript, the whole system would be pointless.

You'll have to manually clear the database and/or remove that specific entry. Every browser does it differently, see http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers for an overview.

Answer (score 2):

The real solution:

1. Install a valid cert
2. Get people to visit your site
3. Send a new header

These days, getting a valid cert is [free](https://letsencrypt.org/), or costs less than a sandwich ($8 or so).

Comment: Now that letsencrypt is a thing, I've moved onto using it.